# GRADE SYNC FAILED

Tags: android-studio

Cause :java.io.tmpdir is set to a directory that doesn't exist:
c:\programdata\order\java\javapath;binC:\program Files(×86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121C:\program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121

Can anyone help me I tried everything searched all forums
And youtube

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.tmpdir` file path is missing.

**By default this value should come from the TMP environment variable on Windows systems**

On [Windows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/14f7b2425c86/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l996), OpenJDK's `get_temp_directory()` function makes a `Win32` API call to `GetTempPath();` this is how on Windows, Java reflects the value of the `TMP` environment variable.

To specify the `java.io.tmpdir` System property, you can invoke the JVM as follows:

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir
```

Comment: Actually iam a begginer and I installed android studio and got this message I didn't understand can u please be more specific where can I type that in my windows

Comment: Have you installed Java JDK ? and also check path In environmental variable, from your question it seems path of incorrect

Comment: Yes I installed Jdk and set the path